# How to have convert notebook command support Chinese character on Mac? I am willing to contribute some code to jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am running jupyter notebook on Mac.

This command converts a notebook file that does not contain Chinese character to pdf successfully.

```
jupyter nbconvert test.ipynb --to pdf
```

When dealing with a notebook file that contains Chinese characters, all the Chinese characters are missing in the generated pdf file.

Is there a way to fix this?

I am willing to contribute some code to [jupyter notebook](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook) project for this, I just don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

`jupyter` uses `nbconvert` to convert `notebook` with **template** to PDF files with process like:

```
notebook -(nbconvert)-> latex -(XeLatex)-> PDF
```

The template that the `nbconvert` used do not support Chinese, causing the problem. By adding package like `xeCJK` and its font in the template, the problem solved.

You can find the base template under `...share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/latex` and named `base.tex.j2`.
Add the following snippet in the template file to make it support Chinese (`MacOS`):

```latex
    \usepackage{xeCJK}
    \setCJKmainfont{STSong}
```

If you want to contribute, you can read the `nbconvert` document here and check the open source code on Github:Jupyter/nbconvert

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this question while researching a similar problem on Windows. Here's my solution.

(1) I converted the ipynb file to latex using NBConvert via command line

```
jupyter nbconvert --to latex "your_path_to_doc.ipynb"
```

(2) I installed the xecjk package using MikTeX

(3) I opened the .tex file from (1) in TeXworks

(4) I inserted

```
\usepackage[slantfont, boldfont]{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Microsoft YaHei}
```

into to the document preamble.

(5) I compiled the document to pdf using XeLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX in TeXworks.

You're on MacOS, so your font will differ, as will (I imagine) how you install xecjk.

Hope this helps.